# ExtJS 4 TreeGrid - referencing parent record from a child record

Tags: extjs, tree, grid, extjs4

I'd like to make a custom renderer where a child record can reference some data from the parent record. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You renderer gets passed in the store, so yes, you can use any (currently loaded) data from the store to render the result.
So something like this should work (untested):

```
column: {
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowInde, colIndex, store, view) {
        return value + (record.parentNode ? ' [' + record.parentNode.get('fieldName') + ']' : '');
    }
}
```

See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column

Comment: This works, thank you. Is there some sort of pattern to these anonymous function parameters or does ExtJS simply 'know' which parameters correspond to which piece of data/property? I'm not using metaData, rowIndex, etc yet they're present in the function params list.

Comment: Oh I see now, there IS a params list documented, duh, silly me!